# Django Generic Relations error: "cannot resolve keyword 'content_object' into field"

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm using Django's Generic Relations to define Vote model for Question and Answer models.

Here is my vote model:

**models.py**

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    user_voted = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
    is_upvote = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # Generic foreign key
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'user_voted')
```

**views.py**

```
        user_voted = MyUser.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
        object_type = request.POST.get('object_type')

        object = None;
        if object_type == 'question':
            object = get_object_or_404(Question, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        elif object_type == 'answer':
            object = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=self.kwargs['pk'])

        # THIS LAST LINE GIVES ME THE ERROR
        vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(user_voted=user_voted, content_object=object)
```

And then I get this error:

```
FieldError at /1/ 
Cannot resolve keyword 'content_object' into field. Choices are: answer, content_type, id, is_upvote, object_id, question, user_voted
```

When I print the "object" to Django console, it prints "Question 1" object. So I don't understand why the line "content_object=object" gives me the field error...

Any ideas :(((???

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`content_object` is a sort of read-only attribute that will retrieve the object specified by fields `content_type` and `object_id`. You should replace your code by the following:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(object)
vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(user_voted=user_voted, content_type=type, object_id=object.id)
```

**Edit:** Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) explicitly remarks:

> Due to the way GenericForeignKey is implemented, you cannot use such fields directly with filters (filter() and exclude(), for example) via the database API. Because a GenericForeignKey isn’t a normal field object, these examples will not work:

```
# This will fail
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(content_object=guido)
# This will also fail
>>> TaggedItem.objects.get(content_object=guido)
```