# Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field

Tags: django

I'm trying to use generic relations, my model looks like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    # Identifiers
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False, related_name = 'posts')
    # Resource
    resource_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    resource_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    resource = GenericForeignKey('resource_type', 'resource_id')

    # Other
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
         unique_together = ('resource_type', 'resource_id',)
```

However, when on my resource I try to get the Post object, using '`SomeResource.posts`' the following exception occurs:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are:
>   date_created, id, resource, resource_id, resource_type,
>   resource_type_id, user, user_id

Why is it looking for `content_type` when I explicitly named it `resource_type` on my `GenericForeignKey`?

Answer (score 14):

I don't see it anywhere in the docs right now, but if you look at the source for `GenericRelation` there are keywords for `content_type_field` and `object_id_field` when you create it. So if you create the relation as `GenericRelation(object_id_field='resource_id', content_type_field='resource_type')` then it should look for the proper fields.

I found this is particularly necessary if you have multiple `GenericForeignKey's` in a single model and thus cannot use the default names.

You can see the source for 1.11 here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py#L291

Comment: Yes, this solve the same issue for me. I see two approaches: **A.)** in the model where the GenericForeignKey is defined, it should stick to default names `content_type`, `object_id`, `content_object`, then it works without extra steps or **B.)** if in the model where the GenericForeignKey is defined, non-default names are used, these non-default names then must be explicitely stated in the related to model as you have described.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a specific reason for using 'resource' instead of 'content' / 'object' ?

If not, I would suggest to change all 3 lines related to the generic relations like this (as well as Meta):

```
 content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
 object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
 content = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I always stick to these field names for generic relations (based on [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType)), even though the documentation mentions the possibility to rename both 'content_type' and 'object_id' (maybe only 'content' must remain unchanged...). I'm not good enough in Django to explain why the behaviour.

Hope it is feasible and works for your project

Comment: I wanted to change them for readability and uniformity, because I think the default naming is a bit clunky.

Comment: Here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239030/django-generic-relations-error-cannot-resolve-keyword-content-object-into-fi) you may have an answer if your issue is with filtering objects... Sorry I can't help more

Comment: No sorry, my issue is not with filtering. It's with retrieving the generic object.